# How to define attributes with multinstances in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class which I want to define a multinstance attribute. How can I do this?

My code is:

```
Class SuperMarket:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = 1
```

And what I need is to define a `self.content.fruits.banana.number`.

Do you have any ideia on how I can do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: You will need several other classes and instanced of those classes inside SuperMarket / other classes

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code wherein you set content, fruit and its number. This is an alternative way rather than creating multiple classes and initializing them in the SuperMarket class.

```
class SuperMarket:

    def __init__(self):
        print 'Initializing fruit data --- '

    def setContent(self, content):
        self.content = content
        return self

    def setFruit(self, fruit):
        self.fruit = fruit
        return self

    def setNumber(self, number):
        self.number = number
        return self

a = SuperMarket().setContent(1).setFruit('banana').setNumber(10)

print a.content #1
print a.fruit #banana
print a.number #10
```